# songs about OS X or iOS?

Tags: macos, ios, music

I know of just one song, but are there other songs out there?

[James Dempsey - Model View Controller](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYvOGPMLVDo)

Comment: very nice idea (from James that is)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

James Dempsey and the Breakpoints do a song every year at WWDC.  Knowing the secret to *which* session will have the song requires knowing some very subtle clues to watch for in some of the Monday sessions.

Besides "Model View Controller" (2003), there's been:

- "Fetch Specifications" - 2001
- "Relationships" - 2002
- "Model View Controller" - 2003
- "[Modelin' Man](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-6hi3KSzzs)" - 2004
- "[Release Me](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4t7fNzwNgzM)" - 2005
- "Endian Reservations" - 2006
- "[I Love View](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0AcrL6vHE8)" - 2007
- "[Designated Initializer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajlESsRXqmM)" - 2008
- "Pasteboard Writin'" - 2009
- "[Anti Patterns](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=video&cd=2&ved=0CDIQtwIwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D2Cx-LIbsgq4&ei=Pq_rTYj7H-zYiAKn7_3hCA&usg=AFQjCNG_pxw1fnM7uZoS99DYisQqjZVNmw)" - 2010

Sorry I can't find all of the videos.

There are also comical songs about Mac OS X.

- "[I'm On A Mac (I'm On A Boat cover)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8FnACj25xM)" - 2008

Answer (score 1):

There is now an entire album of songs about OS X and iOS development.

The album is *Backtrace*.

It contains all of the *James Dempsey and the Breakpoints* songs listed above plus additional materials.

It's available now on iTunes:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/backtrace/id926558924?uo=4&at=11lpkp&ct=11

I hope you enjoy it!

Comment: The link goes to a web page with a button to view in Music (iTunes' successor).  Button doesn't work.  Found the album by using a search in Music, but can't buy it or listen without a subscription to Apple Music.